# how to remember ember-i18n language choice on browser refresh

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

I tried first something like this in my application controller:

```
init123: function() {
  var locale;
  if (this.session.get('lang') === null || this.session.get('lang') === undefined)
    locale = ENV.i18n.defaultLocale;
  else
    locale = this.session.get('lang');

  this.get('i18n').set('locale', locale);
}.on('init'),
```

but this only works when the user is logged in. If not, always the default is set.

Then I tried stuff with the initalizer like on this answer.

[How to set the i18n.locale from within an initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775225/how-to-set-the-i18n-locale-from-within-an-initializer/30776741#30776741) from Artych

But how do I remember the last choice done in the browser?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to persist the preference somewhere. Take a look at the [ember-localforage-adapter](https://github.com/genkgo/ember-localforage-adapter) or [ember-local-storage](https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-local-storage) packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) you can save it into the session.